# iTunes Store: "Your payment method was declined."

Tags: iphone, itunes, applications

Last night I attempted to purchase an app from the App Store on my iPhone 4. The previous day I had purchased an app with no issues, and this time was told that my payment method was invalid. When I clicked 'Continue' to fix my information, everything was correct so I re-inputted my credit card security code and tapped done. No, fail, declined.

I called my bank as I am currently vacationing in Ireland, and if my debit card (the card my iTunes account uses) starts getting declined I will have issues. No, no problems, they had a note in my account that I was traveling, and there are no holds or flags on my spending. She also noted that the iTunes store had requested a verification of $0.99 but had not charged the card for the amount.

I returned to the iTunes store on my iPhone and attempted again to input my credit card information. Still declined. I entered a second credit card. Declined. I opened up iTunes on my laptop (OS X 10.6, iTunes 10) and checked my account information there. No prompt about it being incorrect when I log in, unlike on the iPhone which tells me – even for free apps – that my payment method was declined as soon as I input my password.

I attempted to purchase the app from the store on my computer and sync it to the iPhone. As soon as I click on purchase, I am asked to authenticate. As soon as I authenticate, I am asked to fix my credit card information. As soon as I fix my credit card information, I am returned to the screen I was at previously where I elected to purchase this app (in this case, that screen is the home page of the App Store).

Two different cards, no issues with the bank, no way to get it working in iTunes proper on the desktop or through various attempts in the App Store in the iPhone. Any ideas? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have the exact same issue you are mentioning...

Comment: This happened to me three weeks ago. No problems on my bank acc according to my bank they checked the detyails entered on Itunes and all should be fine. Have tried another bank card (Different bank all details verified and OK their end) but the same problem persists and still waiting an answer from Apple.

Comment: I don't think you can but stuff from the US iTunes stores from outside the US. EULA says : "US Sales Only". Apple claims that they'll enforce "using technology". When I'm abroad, I can't even buy stuff even if the credit card has no problems.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I keep getting that my card has been declined, problem is i'm using paypal, I just tried it using a itunes gift card and it's still telling me my card has been declined.

Comment: There are several reasons for this: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/125846 for an official Apple KB article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "official" way to fix, per Apple, it is to email Apple's iTunes support (iTunesStoreSupport@apple.com), inform them of the problem, and then wait for them to fix it for you on their end. The good news about this solution is that my email was answered very quickly, the support person knew what the issue was and how to fix it, and within a couple days of telling them about the problem they had fixed it and I am up and working again.

After they told me it was fixed, it did take almost exactly 24 hours to take effect, and in the email they told me "wait about 24 hours and try purchasing an app again."

At the time I was having this problem (while traveling abroad) I was in no mood to "wait it out" as other answers have suggested, but since it was handled so capably and promptly by iTunes Support, I wouldn't suggest that as a course of action. It is a known issue for them.

Comment: What email address did you use? I don't see any address published prominently on the iTunes support site.

Comment: iTunesStoreSupport@apple.com — I found it on Apple's site or through iTunes, I can't recall now. I'll also add this to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I actually had this issue before too. I am not sure what caused it, but after waiting a couple of days, it worked again. [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2522048?tstart=0) are people discussing it on the Apple Support Forums, but there doesn't appear to be a resolution. I think mine may have been a transient service issue or something. It never happened again after this.

Comment: Discussion link seems dead.

Answer (score 1):

***THIS WORKED FOR ME***

I spoke with my credit card company, they mentioned the name had to match EXACTLY as on your card, INCLUDING BEING IN CAPS.  Because there is no place for middle name, add it after first name in the app store credit card info, for example First Name: JOHN C Last Name: SMITH.  Once I did this, it worked.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting this problem with Itunes and this is the way I solved it without contacting Apple. 
1. Make sure you have funds on your dedicated card
2. Check details with the bank and inform them of any details that cannot be entered correctly into itunes ie Title Itunes lists Ms, Mrs and Mr but not Miss. 
3. Take off all payment information on Itunes sign out of your account and close Itunes and leave it for about an hour and then re-enter the details.

This works for me but I cannot guarnetee if it will work for anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by logging out of Store in my iPad. Then re-login. At that point, it prompted me to check the payment details. I did the necessary and its gone.

Fire up iTunes in your computer logout, then login again. It should be resolved.