# Unable to change payment information to NONE in iOS Appstore

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

Ever since adding an iTunes gift card to my account, I'm getting verification requests like crazy. I can't even download free apps. It takes me to my payment info and when I try to select none, I continually get a message under the payment info that says "you must verify your payment info to continue"

I don't want a credit card on file and would really like the none option to work. My ID shows I still have iTunes credit.

Comment: Apple really really don't want you to choose none and not have a credit card on file, so expect to type your password in about 10 times, and have the Review screen fail and sessions time out, and it still not work even though you've typed your itunes gift card code in 10 times. Save your sanity and do it all through itunes on your desktop.

Answer (score 16):

Apple is simply trying to make it easier to purchase apps if you decide to do that in the future. Providing the security code on the card lowers the fees Apple pays to the credit card processing company since it is evidence you are in physical possession of the card.

You aren't required to provide a credit card at all just to sign up. When you are prompted for the credit card type, Apple gives the option to chose "None". If you choose this while purchasing a free app, it will allow you to sign up without a credit card.

Apple provides [walkthrough steps for doing this on both a computer and on an iPod touch or iPhone](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2534).

If this method is not available in your country but your country does have iTunes Store gift cards available, you can purchase one gift card and use it to create an account. You'll have to pay a little up front of course, but you won't have to provide a credit card before starting to purchase the free apps.

[image: App Store signup form - No credit card]

[image: iOS App Store signup form - No credit card]

Comment: Please bear in mind that some countries *do not* have the option to select "None". (E.g.: Spain)

Comment: @Mart Also if you chose None you can just sign in and do some little job (like rating music) if you want buy free app iTunes tell you fill your credit card information. so choosing None is useless for downloading free app.

Comment: @Martín I was not aware of that. I added another method using a gift card, is that available?

Comment: @am1 in France, you can download free apps even if you don't enter your credit card information.

Comment: @Loïc, I didn't know that, I must search and find if it really have different method for different country.

Comment: the none option works only in ITUNES 9.....


NOW I AM ENJOYING AND DOWNLOADING APPS.......!!!!!!!

Comment: @Jayant: THERE IS NO NEED TO SHOUT!!!

Comment: This doesn't always work. I'm currently stuck in a loop where I select None, type in all the information including a gift card and the next button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Easier workaround: just use the Change Country option and Apple will reset your payment information.  At that point you can enter "none" for payment method.  (You can select your original country - no need to change to another country and back!)

Answer (score 9):

If you bring an Apple ID to the store that exists (instead of making a new one), you are not presented with the **None** option.

Try the following steps as a work around:

1. Try to purchase a free item in the iTunes or Mac App Store **on a non-iOS device**
2. Log in when prompted
3. Accept any terms you have to
4. If **None** is not an option on the **Review Payment Information** screen, click **Paypal**
5. Click the **To redeem a code, click here** link that appears below
6. *Log in again when prompted*
7. Accept any terms you have to *again*
8. The new **Review Payment Information** screen should allow you to select **None**

Alternatively, clicking **Redeem** in the **Quick Links** box on the main page of the Mac App Store may allow you to bypass steps 1-5. You also can just put in payment method one time, do not make a charge and then remove it.

Lastly, someone that's a family organizer can ask you to join and then you would leave once your account is "verified" into the app store.

Comment: None and Paypal are not presented as options in many countries. If that's you: 1) change country to USA, pick any old city and zip code, 2) select Paypal as option, 3) when transferred to Paypal *cancel* the transaction, 4) when back at previous screen the *None* option should be available. 5) Finish registration. 6) **from desktop computer** run itunes (might have to install it first), login using account from previous, 7) go to account details and change Country and Street Address to what you really need them to be.

Answer (score 3):

Does Apple think you have an unpaid balance? That cause cause the "payment verification" requests. To see if that's the case, check your purchase history. If you do have an outstanding balance, once you pay it you should be able to select "none" as a payment option.

See:

Why can’t I select None when I edit my payment information?
http://support.apple.com/kb/TS5366

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the cause was that my salutation was missing from the info. You can fix this by selecting none and then scrolling down to and make sure all the address fields are complete.

Answer (score 1):

Did you enter your billing address and phone number? Because this happened to me once and it did not let me select none without entering all the "required" info. It seems that you have a none option, so it might work. If not, tap a credit card/payment option, and click done. It will throw and error, so then switch to none(but make sure to enter you address and phone number)

Comment: I found after about 10 goes I had to select a credit card option, then go back to None to get it to work. Please test things Apple!

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have an unpaid order or a authorisation issue with your bank. 
you obviously can't select "none" until the order is paid.

You may want to see this :
Pay an unpaid balance in the iTunes Store - Apple Support
https://support.apple.com/en-ie/HT203005

Answer (score 0):

Another reason you might be prevented from installing free apps is if you have an expired, or otherwise invalid, credit card attached to your Apple ID.   I had that problem.  When I deleted the expired credit card leaving NO payment method I was able to install free apps.